# IntelliJ IDEA: Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven: how do I run an individual test class/case?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I have a java spring-boot project with maven as my build framework.
I do have several plugins configured that do annotation processing during the compilation phase (mapstruct, lombok, etc).

One of those plugins has a bug and doesn't work well within IntelliJ.

That causes my build to fail if I simply try to build a module (all of my annotation processors are properly configured as it worked fine in the past, it's the upgrade to jdk14 caused an avalanche effect, spring-boot along with a bunch of libs and plugins had to be upgraded).

I figured that there is an option to delegate all build/run actions to Maven. And it works pretty well.

[image]

Except that I used to select a SpringBootTest and run it, now, when I do that it initiates a maven sequence, that triggers `clean` and `install` goals.
It doesn't make sense in my case as I have plenty of other modules that are hooked to `compile` goals: Checktyle, PMD, SpotBugs, Surefire, etc.

I would like the execution of a test to compile source code and run that particular test class/case.

Is that doable?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not configurable now. Please vote for [IDEA-198358](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198358).